# Get all the pages inside "Pages" folder

Tags: content-search-web-part

So when going in "Site contents" you have "Pages" list, i have a folder inside it which is called News and i have created some news using a specific template.

Now i'm wondering how do i aim for all my pages inside the "News" folder? When i aim for my "News" url with my content search i only have one url which point to the library, not the individual pages. I do'nt know how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

In the content search web part try applying the filter "Path Contains".

Your search query in the Content search web part should be as shown below.

```
    path:"https://sharepoint.contoso.com/sites/YourSiteUrl/pages/news"
```